# WIX React-native-navigation v2 will not call registerAppLaunchedListener()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am trying to start a project using react-native-navigation, but cannot seem to get on my way.

Right now, the error I receive is that React cannot render the root component, and I have managed to find that the reason (as far as I understand) is that the function I create, Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener, is never called, and I can't seem to find the reason why not. My code is as follows

My App.js file that is the first JS file to be called by the project. The root file of the project so to say

```
const { start} = require('./Navigation')
start();
```

My Navigation.js file, with the start() function called from App.js. Here I am initializing the root screen, in the registerAppLaunchedListener() that is my problem.

```
const { Navigation } = require('react-native-navigation');
const { registerScreens } = require('./screens');
const { Platform } = require('react-native');

function start() {
    console.log("START")
    registerScreens();
    console.log("REGISTERING APP LAUNCH LISTER")
    Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {

        console.log("SETTING ROOT");

        Navigation.setRoot({
            root: {
                stack: {
                  children: [
                    {
                      component: {
                        name: 'navigation.loginscreen'
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
  start
};
```

The index.js file in ./screens that is used to register the screen components to IDs, later used in registerAppLaunchedListener() under setRoot

```
const { Navigation } = require('react-native-navigation');
const LoginScreen = require('./LoginScreen');
const HomeScreen = require('./HomeScreen');

function registerScreens() {
    console.log("REGISTER");
    Navigation.registerComponent('navigation.loginscreen', () => LoginScreen);
    Navigation.registerComponent('navigation.homescreen', () => HomeScreen);
}


module.exports = {
    registerScreens
};
```

And finally the screen I want to display first, the one that never shows up, LoginScreen.js. Very basic.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {BackgroundHex} from '../Backend/Constants'


class LoginScreen extends React.Component{
    render() {

        console.log("HEYEHY")

        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
}

module.exports = LoginScreen;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

I have tried to follow the guide on [the react-native-navigation docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Usage) and their [sample app](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/v2/playground/src) but cannot manage to understand what I am doing different that is messing it up!

My first thought was that I thought it might be something to do with how I export the components and functions, but that does not seem to be the case.

The console logs:
START
REGISTER
REGISTERING APP LAUNCH LISTER

but not SETTING ROOT from registerAppLaunchedListener(), so that's why I believe that is the problem.

Instead, I receive the following error stack

> ▼Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at registerRootComponent.js:35.
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:60)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

Anything that can bring me towards a solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Due to no answer, I switched to (react navigation)[https://reactnavigation.org/] instead. It is a great library, can highly recommend it! @AmitP

Comment: just bumped into that? Any updates here? @AmitP did you manage to solve it? thanks

Comment: @jeevium plz run away from wix navigation. it has taken me days and nights of troubleshooting compilation bugs and various issues over the last year. Since it requires you to modify the native code. It breaks RN upgrades! the advantages it suppose to provide (performace?) are little to zero in compare with reactnavigation, so the choice is obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Register the listener with registerAppLaunchedListener as soon as possible - it should be one of the first lines in your index.js file. If you're observing a "white screen" or a hanging splash screen after relaunching your app, it probably means Navigation.setRoot isn't called once the app has launched. Perhaps the listener was registered too late. - From the docs